# "sh: 1: react-scripts: not found" In Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a Docker container that fails to do a npm install for a react.js app that is cloned in the container when it is built. Would anybody know how to resolve the issue?

Error:

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! myrideweb@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myrideweb@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-19T04_00_09_065Z-debug.log
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

Run apt-get update

Run apt-get install curl -y

Run curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x

Run apt-get install -y nodejs

Run apt-get install -y git

Run apt-get install npm -y

Run apt-get update -y

Run git clone https://github.com/sdrafahl/TerraWeb.git

WORKDIR /TerraWeb

Run npm install -g --save npm@latest

...
```

Comment: npm install from package.json ?

Comment: You need to run `npm install` in your dockerfile

Answer (score 14):

I managed to work around this by changing the `start` setting under the `scripts` section of the `package.json` file:

`"start: "react-scripts start"`

to:

`"start: "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start"`

I use the classic node base image but it should work more or less the same. I am still investigating why NPM is not able to resolve `react-scripts` when running inside Docker, any further help is very welcome :-)

Comment: may as well use `npx` instead of the direct path to the node modules bin

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when 'react-scripts' was listed under the 'devDependencies' in the package.json file. Moving it to the "dependencies" section solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `package-lock.json` and re-installing packages with `npm install` before building the container solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem recently and I was able to solve it, however, I don't like the solution very much but I think it's OK since it should run in `Docker` or in you local machine. That being said, my suggestion is to update the `package.json` with the following:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "$(npm bin)/react-scripts start",
  }
}
```

[npm-bin docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-bin)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with react-scripts@4.0.1. I uninstalled and re-installed and that seemed to do the trick.

1. `npm uninstall react-scripts`
2. `npm install -D react-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just managed to solve this problem in few simple steps, and i hope these instructions will help you too.

I run a docker with Ubuntu on Windows 10, and I share the `node_modules` folder by volume if this sounds familiar to you, so I believe this solution will help you.
Accidentally I installed the node modules from my Windows user, and that what cause the whole permissions problems.

So what I did is to delete the `node_modules` directory.
Then I installed the node modules from the Ubuntu Terminal, run `npm install`.

You may have to install npm on your Ubuntu, I downloaded the nvm installation file with curl with those instructions, [How to install node on WSL for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl), and then you may run `npm install` and then the react script will be able to run.

After you run `npm install` from Ubuntu, build and run your dockers.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when running docker-compose,I've tried all of the above and nothing has solved the problem. I ended up running the `docker-compose rm` command, deleting the historical containers, and re-running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, which solved my problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding `**/node_modules` to the .dockerignore file.

I guess I was copying `node_modules` from the source folder when I was building the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, turned out that an additional quote snuck into my yarn install command:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc" \
    yarn install                                  # ^ typo doh!
```

This would build without error, only figured it out building with no cache and not seeing packages install.