# React App using DOCKER gives -sh: react-scripts: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was trying to build a dockeraized react app.

The Docker conifguration is given below

**docker/Dockerfile.dev**

```
# Stage 1: Build React app
FROM node:18.13.0-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@9.8.0
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  tmf-dev:
    container_name: tmf-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "9001:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  app:
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tmf",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**docker-compose build --no-cache** command works well. It successfully builds the container without any error.

But when I run **docker-compose up** it gives the below output  -

```
Creating network "turf-management-frontend_default" with the default driver
Creating tmf-dev ... done
Attaching to tmf-dev
tmf-dev    | 
tmf-dev    | > tmf@0.1.0 start
tmf-dev    | > react-scripts start
tmf-dev    | 
tmf-dev    | sh: react-scripts: not found
```

I already tried the [solves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920521/sh-1-react-scripts-not-found-in-docker) here but with no result.

Comment: i think you forget to tun npm i in your docker. so all of your app dependencies not installed.

Comment: I did ran the command in the docker file "npm install ..... ". You can see it on the Dockerfile.dev. Am i missing something here?

Comment: this line? RUN npm install -g npm@9.8.0
 this install the npm package globaly in your docker. your docker is node so i think you not need this at all.

try to :
RUN npm install

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the volumes section in your service. This volume will first be ready, when your container has been created. So in your dockerfile you perform the npm install and when the container is created you overwrite the "app" folder in the container with the content of . (The root of your project folder).

Lets assume you have the following project:

```
|-app
|   |-public (Folder containing the index.tml etc...)
|   |-src    (Folder containing App.js etc...)
|   |-package.json
|   |-package-lock.json
|-docker
|   |-Dockerfile.dev
|-docker-compose.yaml
```

And your docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  tmf-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
```

And you Dockerfile.dev looks like this:

```
# Stage 1: Build React app
FROM node:18.13.0-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -g npm@9.8.1
CMD ["tail","-F","Something"]
```

Then you can go to your project root folder and execute:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This will start your container and install npm 9.8.1 globally.

The command `tail -F Something` will do that your container will not exit directly again.

Now run:

```
docker-compose exec tmf-dev npm install
```

This will create the node_modules folder in your project and install the needed dependencies.

Then you can build the app with:

```
docker-compose exec tmf-dev npm run build
```

And start the app with:

```
docker-compose exec tmf-dev npm run start
```

There is no need to expose port 3000 in your Dockerfile. Instead you have the portmapping in the docker-compose file. Mapping your local port 3030 to the containers port 3000.

Now you should be able to access your app on http://127.0.0.1:3030

If your run the app in the browser under the ip given after npm run start as "On Your Network", then if you make changes in /app/src/App.js this should automaticly reload the page when saved.

**Hint:**

If you run:

```
docker-compose exec tmf-dev /bin/sh
```

Then you will be logged in to the container. This only works when the container is running. Here you can get a better view on what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It provided me with valuable insights, and I was able to identify the problem and solve it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would be great if you could post your solution as answer, so that other people heading the same problem can find help here.